# Using a transient field in HQL

Tags: java, jpa, hql

I have a field this is mounted in run-time, like a join of another fields. Look:

```
public String getNumeroCip() {

        if (this.getId() == null) {
            return "BR0000000000000";
        }

        String idFormated = String.format("%011d", this.getId());
        return "BR" + idFormated + this.produto.getProduto().getSufixo();
    }
```

This is my field, mounted in run-time. I can call it doing: bean.numeroCip.

But if i try use this in a HQL, like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Ar.findByNumeroArOrCip", query = "SELECT c FROM AR c "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.produto "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.situacao "
                + "WHERE c.numeroAr = :numeroAr OR c.numeroCip = :numeroCip")
```

I got the following error when i try start tomcat server:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: Ar.findByNumeroArOrCip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transient fields cannot be used in HQL queries. In the end HQL query is translated to the SQL query, which is then executed against database. Database is not aware of fields of Java objects.

Comment: So, the unique solution is create my field in database. So sad.